# AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera giving error

Tags: ios, avcapturedevice

I am using Socket scanner sdk in my application. I am using xcode 7.3.
The sdk provided by Socket scanner it self. when i tried to run their sample, it is giving error below:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera", referenced from:

-[SoftScan start:] in libScanApiCore.a(SoftScanController.o)

i am using standard architectures, armv7 and arm64.

i tried to add other linker flag -ObjC- but not working.
Anyone know how it can resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`x86_64` is the architecture of your computer, so I assume you run this in the simulator. Since the simulator has no camera, it is very likely that it crashes at this point, probably because the `_AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera` symbol is defined only if a wide angle camera is available (the actual hardware). Try running it on your device instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When i tried to install it in my device it is giving                   error.Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera", referenced from:
      -[SoftScan start:] in libScanApiCore.a(SoftScanController.o)

Comment: Have yo added `AVFoundation` as a dependency? You can verify if you select the app's target, under General --> Linked Frameworks and Libraries

Answer (score 0):

The AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera is defined in iOS 10